# QML Shortcut Hold event

Tags: qt, qml

I'm working on a Qt app, and developing most of the UI in QML.  It will be mostly keyboard driven, and has quite a few pages/popups.  So to avoid having a potential focus scope catastrophe, I've written most of the keybindings as Shortcuts.

Some of the shortcuts are to be activated when a key is held.  These keys are physical buttons on a piece of external hardware.  For instance, if Physical Key 1 is pressed, do action A.  If Physical Key 1 is held for 2 seconds, do action B.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What did you already do? What problem did you face? Please, provide you code here.

Comment: Actually, you rather need a "ShortCut Release" (and a QTimer) but I never heard about this. Therefore, I would instead recommend to research the Qt doc. about event filters. May be, the solution is the filtering of key press and key release events (and a QTimer).

Comment: How about something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33914142/5393249)

Comment: @M.Lutz Just similar to what I had in mind. I mentioned the event filters as T. Wallis worries about the "potential focus scope catastrophe".

Comment: @M. Lutz that looks promising.  Previously I had been using a Key event with a timer, and that worked decently.

The reason I mentioned 'focus scope catastrophe' is largely due to the fact that I have quite a large amount of popups and submenus, and only have a handful of buttons to use.  This is mostly because of the hardware.